# Python : How to sort if the list contains the number and strings at the same time?

Tags: python

In my list, I had a mix of number and strings and the sort() doesn't not work on it, unfortunately. Any look around for this?

Please help.

`myList = ['rohit', 'mandiwal', 32, 7701]`

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you keep your desired ordering secret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use a sort key that creates a tuple that places strings or numbers first without having to compare them directly.

Method: In each tuple, numbers have a 0 for the 1st element, strings have a 2.

This keeps numbers and string from being compared and places numbers first.  Can reverse this by making numbers 1 and strings 0.

```
myList = ['rohit', 'mandiwal', 32, 7701, 3.5]
result = sorted(myList, key = lambda x: (isinstance(x, str), x))
print(result)
```

Simplified key with tip from @StefanPochmann

**Output**

```
3.5, 32, 7701, 'mandiwal', 'rohit']
```

Comment: Or `lambda x: (isinstance(x, str), x)` or `lambda x: (type(x), x)`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your list into two sorted sub-lists, one containing numbers (ints and floats) and the other containing everything else.  Return the combined result.

```
myList = ['rohit', 'mandiwal', 32, 7701, 3.5]
result = (
    sorted(n for n in myList if isinstance(n, (int, float))) 
    + sorted(word for word in myList if not isinstance(word, (int, float)))
)
>>> result
[3.5, 32, 7701, 'mandiwal', 'rohit']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list to sorted  alphabetically by treating each element as a string, then use `sorted(myList, key=str)`.  The basic idea is to use a *key* function to transform each list element into a value whose type supports comparison while the transformation enables the required sort ordering.